# Drop foreign key using subquery to get its name

Tags: mysql

I need to drop a foreign key, but I don't know its name. 
**I don't want to drop all indexes from table**.

I'm trying to do this with following subquery

```
ALTER TABLE `onboarding_requests`
  DROP FOREIGN KEY (SELECT `CONSTRAINT_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` 
  WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'onboarding_requests' AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'partner_responsible');
```

but it returns:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(SELECT `CONSTRAINT_NAME` FROM
>   `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` WHERE `TABL' at line 2

Comment: @juergend returns one result

Comment: Try `SHOW INDEX FROM onboarding_requests`

Comment: Returns 6 results. The thing is I don't want to know the key's name, I want to make this query work regardless of foreign key's name.

Comment: marked as duplicate by juergen d - "This question already has an answer here: mysql dropping all indexes from table" - where I stated that I want to drop all indexes from table?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use variable substitution in data definition statements.  In other words, you must give the literal name of the foreign key in a `DROP FOREIGN KEY` statement.

How can you work around this inherent limitation of SQL? All SQL, by the way, not just MySQL, prohibits this.  Write a small program in your favorite language (python? php>) to retrieve the names of the data entities from the information schema, then use string concatenation to create the data definition statements you need.